# Returning each value from the for loop in C++

Tags: c++

How can I return each value of the loop?

I'm trying this but it returned first value but I need every value of the loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    signal = 10 * i;`
    return signal;
}
```

Comment: Once the return is hit the function will exit returning that 1 value. You can't keep looping after the return.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some more details about your problem. I don't know if that loop is in main, in a function somewhere else, etc. I don't know if what you're trying to do would work with a function as suggested below or maybe a callback you pass in, etc. Be specific.

Comment: this loop is in the function which is in the class. In main() I am calling this function  using object of the class

Comment: Definitely an X-Y problem. If you can share more details pertaining to the design, someone might offer a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you really need that values, simply use vector and return container

```
std::vector<int> getValues(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> container;

    for(int i=0; i < n; ++i)
        container.push_back(10*i);

    return container;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> container = getValues(10);

    for(int val : container)
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

or change your code design to call function in each loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  signal =10*i;`
  function_that_needs_every_value(signal);
}
```

Comment: thanks! this loop inside a function and the function is in the class, I need this value in main() function

Comment: You question is too broad and looks like XY-problem.